# if we mix bleaching powder in water will this be converted to Sodium Hypochlorite?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

if we mix bleaching powder in water will this be converted to Sodium Hypochlorite ?

Comment: by the way, how does a mixed salt of calcium hypochlorite, calcium chlorite, calcium chloride and water ( as quoted by NCERT, but generally hypochlorite being the actual active component), which doesn't have any sodium, suddenly become sodium hypochlorite?

Comment: actually, both are oxidising agents which provide nascent oxygen atoms. so, both have similar action and hence, bleaching powder is sometimes also used instead of sodium hypochlorite, just that, I think, sodium hypochlorite is a bit more active than bleaching powder when both are taken in the same weights.

Answer (score 1):

Bleaching powder is made of Calcium Hypochlorite mixed with some other Calcium compounds in various proportion. It does not contain any Sodium compounds. So in water it will not be converted to Sodium Hypochlorite.